# TensorFlow: Contracting a dimension of two tensors via dot product

Tags: numpy, tensorflow, theano

I have two tensors, `a` of rank 4 and `b` of rank 1.  I'd like to produce `aprime`, of rank 3, by "contracting" the last axis of a away, by replacing it with its dot product against `b`.  In numpy, this is as easy as `np.tensordot(a, b, 1)`.  However, I can't figure out a way to do this in Tensorflow.

How can I replace the last axis of a tensor with a value equal to that axis's dot product against another tensor (of course, of the same shape)?

**UPDATE**:

1. I see in Wikipedia that this is called the "Tensor Inner Product" https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dot_product#Tensors aka tensor contraction.  It seems like this is a common operation, I'm surprised that there's no explicit support for it in Tensorflow.
2. I believe that this may be possible via `tf.einsum`; however, I have not been able to find a generalized way to do this that works for tensors of any rank (this is probably because I do not understand `einsum` and have been reduced to trial and error)

Answer (score 1):

Aren't you just using `tensor` in the sense of a multidimensional array?  Or in some disciplines a tensor is 3d (vector 1d, matrix 2d, etc).  I haven't used `tensorflow` but I don't think it has much to do with `tensors` in that linear algebra sensor.  They talk about data flow graphs.  I'm not sure where the `tensor` part of the name comes from.

I assume you are talking about an expression like:

```
In [293]: A=np.tensordot(np.ones((5,4,3,2)),np.arange(2),1)
```

resulting in a (5,4,3) shape array.  The `einsum` equivalent is

```
In [294]: B=np.einsum('ijkl,l->ijk',np.ones((5,4,3,2)),np.arange(2))
```

`np.einsum` implements Einstine Notation, as discussed here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstein_notation.  I got this link from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tensor_contraction

You seem to be talking about straight forward `numpy` operations, not something special in `tensorflow`.

Comment: TensorFlow indeed handles tensor operations like these.  It's advantage over numpy is that it avoids going back and forth between Python, with much greater speed.  From the site: _"is an open source software library for numerical computation using data flow graphs. Nodes in the graph represent mathematical operations, while the graph edges represent the multidimensional data arrays (tensors) communicated between them"

Comment: And it makes heavy use of `numpy` too; I bet `tf.einsum` is actually `np.einsum`.  It does have a significant body of compiled code, which is too large to load on my computer.  So I can only answer these questions from a `numpy` persepective.

Comment: It can't use numpy, because, behind the scenes, Python isn't in the loop

Comment: OK, a current issue for `einsum` in `tensorflow`: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/4722

Answer (score 0):

I would first add 3 dimensions of size 1 to b so that it can be broadcast along the 4'th dimension of a.

`b = tf.reshape(b, (1, 1, 1, -1))`

Then you can multiply b and a and it will broadcast b along all of the other dimensions.

`a_prime = a * b`

Finally, reduce the sum along the 4'th dimension to get rid of that dimension and replace it with the dot product.

`a_prime = tf.reduce_sum(a_prime, [3])`

Answer (score 0):

This seems like it would work (for the first tensor being of any rank):

```
   tf.einsum('...i,i->...', x, y)
```

Comment: This won't work, because `tf.einsum` does not yet support `...` notation.